# Select on jsonb not returning any values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, select, jsonb

I'm trying to select values from a jsonb column, `payload`. The json has a format like

```
{"id" : 123456, "email": "ben@email.com", "items" : [{}, {}, ...]}
```

Using ActiveRecord, I'm trying ModelRecord.select("payload ->> 'email'").all and all the records are being returned `#<ModelRecord id: nil>`.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or I'm misunderstanding the correct use.

PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Rails 5.1.3

Comment: What are you expecting the results of the example call to be?

Comment: @jvillian i'm not sure how ruby would format the object in a `puts`, but I was expecting the value for the key `email` to be returned

Comment: Sorry, still unclear. You're expecting an array of emails? A collection of ModelRecords? A specific ModelRecord?

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the correct use.

> I'm trying `ModelRecord.select("payload ->> 'email'")` and all the records are being returned `[#<ModelRecord id: nil>, ... ]`

This is how AR works, AR maps columns to the model attributes, `payload` is a jsonb column and for that reason isn't mapped properly. Your records are valid and you can access `select`-ed attribute in a plain way, try it:

```
col = ModelRecord.select("payload ->> 'email'")
col.first.payload
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I think you are trying to get the only the email column if it is, you can do this.

```
def index
    @emails = Model.select(:email)
end
```

hope it helps.

Comment: `email` is part of a `jsonb` column (`payload`). Will `select` work in that case?